# node basic-auth - pass basic authentication credentials in URL not working

Tags: node.js, basic-authentication

I have tried http://admin:admin@localhost:8066/admin/ but it didnt work. In previous projects, it worked, I wonder if any mistakes I made?

```
module.exports = function (request, response, next) {
  var user = auth(request);
  if (!user || !config_credential[user.name] || config_credential[user.name].password !== user.pass) { 
    response.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Authorization Required"');
    return response.status(401).send();
  }
    return next();
};
```

And added the middleware.

```
app.use("/admin", auth, xxxx );
```

ps. is using node basic-auth

The reason I want to do is to run the admin cron jobs in server.

Comment: what package are you using? `basic-auth`?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty yes

Answer (score 0):

It is found that if I changed the host table, it finally works without using localhost